# Android: bound service can't send first message, all other messages go through. Why does this happen, how to fix it?

Tags: android, service, message-queue

I have an android activity and a corresponding service, where the activity is just a UI and the service calculates what to display. The service is bound to the activity.

First I establish a connection:

in the Activity.java file:

```
final Messenger _messenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler(new WeakReference<>(this)));
Messenger _serviceMessenger = null;

private ServiceConnection _connection = new ServiceConnection()
{
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
    {
        _serviceMessenger = new Messenger(service);
        try
        {
            // sending the initial welcome message
            Message m = Message.obtain(null, ForegroundService.BIND_SERVICE);
            m.replyTo = _messenger;
            _serviceMessenger.send(m);
        }
        catch(RemoteException ex)
        {
            _serviceMessenger = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
    {
        _serviceMessenger = null;
    }
};

private static class IncomingHandler extends Handler
{
    private WeakReference<MyActivity> _parent;

    IncomingHandler(WeakReference<MyActivity> parent)
    {
        super();
        _parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Activity: Received message");
        MyActivity ta = _parent.get();
        switch(msg.what)
        {
            case ForegroundService.LOCATION_UPDATED:
                if(msg.obj == null)
                {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Activity: msg null");
                    ta.setTexts("", null, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Activity: msg ok");
                    LocWithName loc = (LocWithName)msg.obj;

                    ta.setTexts(loc.getName(), Double.toString(loc.getHossz()), Double.toString(loc.getSzel()));

                    Chronometer chronometer = ta.findViewById(R.id.chronom);
                    chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    chronometer.start();
                }
                break;
            case ForegroundService.LOST_GPS:
                ta.setTexts("", "unknown", "unknown");
                break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

in activity onCreate:

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, ForegroundService.class);
            startIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);

            bindService(startIntent, _connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            startService(startIntent);
```

and in the service java file:

```
final Messenger _messenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler(new WeakReference<>(this)));
Messenger _activityMessenger = null;

private static class IncomingHandler extends Handler
{
    WeakReference<ForegroundService> _parent;

    IncomingHandler(WeakReference<ForegroundService> parent)
    {
        super();
        _parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // received welcome message, now we know who to reply to
        if(msg.what == ForegroundService.BIND_SERVICE)
        {
            _parent.get()._activityMessenger = msg.replyTo;
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "received reply address for messenger"); // after 1st edit
        }
        else
        {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}

private void sendMessageToUI(int message, LocWithName newLoc)
{
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Service: sending message to UI");
    if(_activityMessenger != null)
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "messenger not null"); // after 1st edit
        try
        {
            _activityMessenger.send(Message.obtain(null, message, newLoc));
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Service: message sent");
        }
        catch(RemoteException ex)
        {
            // activity is dead
            _activityMessenger = null;
        }
    }
}
```

then I start sending messages via the sendMessageToUI() function periodically from the service, namely every 5 seconds. The service's `onStartCommand` runs the first UI update immediately, which reschedules itself for every other iteration.

What I know:

- the first immediate "UI update" in the service *does run* as logcat shows me the "sending message to UI" text at the correct time
- all other updates run
- all other updates deliver their messages successfully (which means that the first was stopped by `_serviceMessenger` being null, not the RemoteException, because the catch block would stop all later messages)
- the welcome message from the activity to the service arrives as it is a necessity for further replies from the service

What I have tried:

- in the activity, first bind then start the service (example code is in this state, initially it was the other way around), so `_activityMessenger` isn't null by the time it has to send first message
- send a "burner message" so that is the one that doesn't get delivered instead of actually important messages
- search google for similar problems to no avail - where there are problems, it doesn't work at all, not just the first time around
- search this site for similar problems, same result as with google

Since there are five seconds between the first and the second message, I suspect it is an issue with the speed of initializing something, but I couldn't get further than that. So what exactly happens here and why doesn't it work?

EDIT 1: at the suggestion of @pskink, I added Log.d()-s. It turns out the activity only sends the "welcome message" with reply address ***after*** the first run of the UI updater despite being called earlier than `startService`.

Also, the code sending the messages, after @pskink asking:

in service class:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable updateUI = new Runnable()
{
    // do work to get the information to display
    // in this code I set "int message" to one of the constants handled by the activity's IncomingHandler and "LocWithName newLoc" to a useful value or null

    sendMessageToUI(message, newLoc);
    handler.removeCallbacks(updateUI);
    handler.postDelayed(updateUI, 5000);
}
```

in service onStartCommand:

```
handler.post(updateUI);
```

Comment: i dont see `sendMessageToUI` to be called anywhere in your code, also add some `Log.d` inside the `if` (before `try`) in `sendMessageToUI` method

Comment: @pskink updated the question with some information and code

Comment: what do you need `onStartCommand` for if you are binding to your service? do not call `startService` - just use `bindService`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is assuming that the `bindService()` and `startService()` calls block until the service has been "bound" or "started", respectively. The reality is that `onServiceConnected()` won't get called until sometime *after* `onCreate()` returns. Likewise, the order you call them in is basically meaningless; the OS doesn't guarantee that the service will handle the binding or the `onStartCommand()` first or second, in this case.

To fix, delete the call to `startService()` (as @pskink suggested); the service is started by virtue of the fact that you are binding to it. `onStartCommand()` will no longer be called. Instead, have the Service kick off the `updateUI` Runnable when it gets the `ForegroundService.BIND_SERVICE` message. This allows you to establish the appropriate "happens before" relationships -- namely, that the ServiceConnection binding "happens before" you start trying to use `_activityMessenger` to send messages.